# Does the word 'resonates' work here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I am buying a music related gift for someone and having it engraved, so I can't be too wordy.

The phrase I'm thinking about is

> Your compassion resonates loudly, Thank you.

What I am trying to convey is I am grateful for their compassion and kindness they have shown me and won't soon be forgotten. I'm using resonates and loudly due to the music theme as it make sense with what the gift is. But does resonate make sense this way?

Comment: I am not sure what the best choice would be but resonates here does not seem quite right to me.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right that id doesn't work because it resonates seems to be more of "I relate to your compassion" when I want to say I felt your compassion deeply and thank you for it. I was using resonate cause it has a loose tie in to music. I'll keep thinking on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem quite right to me.

"Resonate" means to produce a sound through vibration. In both a literal and figurative sense, it really describes how *far* sound, or whatever it is describing, reaches - not how *loud* it is. In a literal example, a loud noise may not resonate outdoors, but the same loud noise may resonate inside an empty space where there are walls to bounce off.

When we speak of something 'resonating' in a figurative sense, we normally mean it has a far reach, or a powerful effect that *continues* with us, or perhaps that it is *enduring*, like something that resonates or reverberates.

It might be better to simply say:

> Your compassion resonates.

Or, if you must use an adverb,

> Your compassion resonates *strongly*.

Comment: Well, the gift is a bridge used for string instruments, which is used to help produce louder sound. Which is why I went with loudly and resonates. I was trying to tie everything together between the gift and thanking them for being so compassionate. Strongly might work. I might just have to skip trying to link the gift to the thank you message and just leave the music portion out of the engraving. Thanks for the suggestion.